# Difference between "Eclipse Indigo" and "Eclipse Juno"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo

Currently I'm using *Eclipse Indigo* (v3.7) for [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) WebDriver automation tests with Java. There is also *Eclipse Juno* (v3.8 - 4.2) available that I have never used.

What's the difference between *Eclipse Indigo* and *Eclipse Juno*?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html

Comment: This could've been solved easily if you had just did some research. Also i see no point of tagging Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: They are simply the names for different versions. Juno is the newer version as J comes after I in the alphabet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since 2006, the Eclipse Foundation has coordinated an annual Simultaneous Release. Each release includes the Eclipse Platform as well as a number of other Eclipse projects.
So far, each Simultaneous Release has occurred on the fourth Wednesday of June.

*Eclipse Indigo* corresponds to platform version 3.7, while *Eclipse Juno* - to platform version 4.2. *Juno* has a lot of improvements on the UI, but this results in a bit slower performance that the previous versions. Personally, I would prefer using *Indigo* rather than using *Juno*.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Juno has entirely a GUI with a lot of visual improvements. Although by design it is a lot more functional, it has been proved that Juno is quite slow, and I won't recommend using it at present.

From a Selenium point of view I don't think there would be a reason to switch to the newer version of Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 had some critical performance issues, which were fixed in Juno 4.2.2. This new release is available since March.
Although 3.8 might still be somewhat more stable; from a pure performance standpoint, there is no more reason to recommend against using 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Juno was a LOT slower than Indigo, particularly when moving from one editor window to another. In fact I upgraded to Juno then downgraded again a week or so later as I found Juno unbearably slow, even on a quad core i7 PC.

The current release of Eclipse (at the time that I write this) is 'Kepler'. I'm now using Kepler for my mobile web app and Android development.

So, in summary, **skip Juno and go straight to Kepler** - here's the link; http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Hope this helps.