# Android Eclipse Indigo, Luna, Juno and networking

Tags: android, eclipse, android-networking, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-luna

What's the difference between Eclipse Indigo and  Eclipse Luna with respect to making android applications ? Is Luna and Juno better for making apps which involve network modules like  connectivity, uploading etc.

I have already referred this link :
[Difference between "Eclipse Indigo" and "Eclipse Juno"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518030/difference-between-eclipse-indigo-and-eclipse-juno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android Application Development` on Eclipse depends on `ADT` of `Eclipse`.  `Indigo` or `Luna` have no absolute relation with `Android Development`. The same version of `ADT` for `Eclipse` could be plugged in `Indigo` or `Luna`. So versions of `ADT` for `Eclipse` matter but not those of `Eclipse`

Comment: But, still if we were to consider other aspects, what would be the difference between them ?

Comment: Of course, yes, just like the evolution of `ADT`. They will increase some features every time. Just like `Android API`, just like `Android Studio`, Just like `IntelliJ`, just like `NetBeans`